# Why is Tomcat creating my application at the context path of the WAR file location?

Tags: tomcat, war, tomcat8

I have a remote server with a Tomcat instance onto which I am attempting to deploy a WAR file at the ROOT context. This is the complete path to the WAR file:

> C:\Users\adminsg\Desktop\doj\war\ROOT.war

When I upload the WAR using the file picker, it deploys the WAR to the context path `/C:UsersadminsgDesktopdojwarROOT`, and the `:` breaks the path. The same thing happened when I moved the ROOT.war to the same drive as the Tomcat instance.

The only change I made was to increase the file size limit to 100MB to accommodate a bigger application. I have not ever had this happen before, and I have deployed dozens of applications on Tomcat servers.

Is there any way to get Tomcat to stop creating the context path this way, or is my only option to deploy using the manual context path deployer?

**EDIT**

The error seems to be with the Part.getSubmittedFileName() method in the upload() method of HTTPServletManager. This error only occurs on the remote server, not on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround that involves editing the Tomcat code. I narrowed down the issue to the `ApplicationPart.getSubmittedFileName()` method, where line 152:

`fileName = HttpParser.unquote(fileName.trim());`

was removing the backslashes from the file path. I removed that line and the upload worked correctly.

If there is a better way to do this, please answer the question. Thanks!